# Se Puede descodificar decodeURIComponent() en PHP

Tags: php, javascript-objeto

tengo una pagina que utiliza el comando decodeURIComponent() para enmascarar una url similar al ejemplo en esta pagina https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeURIComponent.asp, como puedo hacer una function para desemascarar pero usando PHP.?

```
var uri = "https://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
var uri_enc = encodeURIComponent(uri);
var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(uri_enc);
var res = uri_enc + "<br>" + uri_dec;
```

Comment: Prueba con [urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.urldecode.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En PHP seria con urldecode().
Te dejo un ejemplo exacto al que has puesto en PHP:

```
$uri = "https://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
$uri_enc = urlencode($uri);
$uri_dec = urldecode($uri_enc);
$res = $uri_enc . "<br>" . $uri_dec;
```